# MATLAB Opening Examples and findpeaks()

Tags: matlab

I have two issues. First I can't figure out how to properly enter commands `openExample('matlab_featured/intro')`

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/basic-matrix-operations.html
However, if I go top Help->Example and open up examples from there it works fine.

My second issue is that findpeaks() doesn't seem to work. For instance, the code below causes and error at the findpeaks() command.

```
data = [25 8 15 5 6 10 10 3 1 20 7]
plot(data)

pks = findpeaks(data)
```

I'd try opening the example, but I can't find it in the documentation via MATLAB, but I can find it if I go to their site.

Comment: please supply more information, which error do you get?

Comment: both give me the error 'Undefined function or variable 'findpeaks./OpenExample'.

Comment: Found the issue. For some reason the signal processing toolbox was not installed.

Answer (score 0):

1. The example can be opened just by entering 'intro' in the command
   line.
2. There is a documentation about findpeaks. Just type 'findpeaks' in
   the command window and press 'F1' on your keyboard immediately.